# export notes within ebook to android?

Tags: notes.app, books, android, ebook

switching from my iphone 5s to a samsung A6, I am wondering if there is any option to include my notes in my ebooks, transfer them to my android phone, continue to read on that phone and also still having my notes in the ebook.

Would that be possible somehow?

Comment: What ebook reader are you using?

Comment: on my iphone the standard ibooks app. On my samsung device: I have not chosen one yet

Comment: I think the only way is to use the same app on both e,g, Kindle or other proprietary app - or Marvin which only works with non DRM books

Comment: @Mark https://www.tuneskit.com/ibook-tips/read-ibooks-on-android.html

Comment: I tried Kindle but I did not find a way to open my own epub file. I have not installed Lithium but I do not have the notes I made in iOS's app 'Books'